# Close nested form

Tags: c#, winforms

So i have that aplication:
[Menu Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5PM5.png)

and when i press the button "Terminar sessão" it's supposed to log out (and its works)
but when i went back to login the menu does not close!

[Login Picture after log out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l57NM.png)

I am using nested form, the form ends session is closing but not the menu.

This is my menu.cs:

```
private Form activeForm = null;

    private void openChildForm(Form childForm)
    {
        if (activeForm != null) activeForm.Close();
        activeForm = childForm;
        childForm.TopLevel = false;
        childForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        childForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        panelChildForm.Controls.Add(childForm);
        panelChildForm.Tag = childForm;
        childForm.BringToFront();
        childForm.Show();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.Visible = false;
        openChildForm(new Transferências());
        Slidepanel.Height = (button2.Height - 15);
        Slidepanel.Top = (button2.Top + 10);
    }
```

and on "Transferências" form i have it:

```
private void Sessao_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Tem a certeza que deseja terminar sessão?", "Terminar Sessão", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            this.Hide();
            Login login = new Login();
            login.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
```

i already tried Menu.Close(); but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

With the amount of information you provide, it is quite hard to tell what the problem might be. Did you try to debug it to verify that your program actually tries to execute `Menu.Close()`?

If you show your code people might be able to help you more.

Comment: i'm sorry, can u check it now?

Comment: Instead of using this overcomplicated `openChildForm()` method, why don't you create an instance of `Transferências()` and then call its constructor? You could then place the codes into the form's constructor which you can change the appearance of the form with.